# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function check () on a no

Tags: jquery, ajax, opencart, internal-server-error

thanks for your interest. I am seeing such an error when I look at the logs from PLesk: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function check () on a non-object in C: \ Inetpub \ vhosts \ trendbirter \ httpdocs \ catalog \ model \ checkout \ order. Php on line 267

I am getting such an error at image below while OpenCart complete the pay option. How could this be solved? hi when I want to click Continue button to continue the order after i finish my payment method then it goes to Checkout Confirmation" The continue button to checkout confirmation does not function it freeze like no action to take. but i look in code. i go to some javascript code. to continue it i try to trace which action it will take i think this javascript

They have the same problem with me. They have solved the problem here, but I do not know how they do it Opencart Fatal error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273 ... 6_41827508

NOTE: This problem started after installing the "VQMOD" and "QUICKCHECKOUT" Modules. I'm using Opencart 2.3x

Answer (score 0):

VQMOD is only for OpenCart 1.x. You have to use OCMOD for OpenCart 2.x. Try delete VQMOD and QUICKCHECKOUT module and reinstall module using OCMOD. [This](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-new-modification-system-in-opencart-2--cms-25547) may help.
Do backup first.